# Can not enable Contact Distance Search under CiviCRM modules

Tags: search, installation

[image: CiviCRM Contact Distance Search checkbox is disabled]

I have installed CiviCRM 4.7 and CMS is Drupal 7.56
CiviCRM Contact Distance Search is showing disabled in the modules list.
Why is it disabled? how to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CiviCRM Contact Distance Search requires [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module and since your system is missing required modules you won't be able to enable it. Once you install Views module you will need to [configure](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/) it with civicrm so that drupal can access data from civicrm.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you very much Pradeep. I installed ctools and views,  I could enable Contact Distance Search.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I have enabled Contact Distance Search, given permission and added Google Map API Key in configuration. I have also added lat lon in Contact Individual details. I expect now it will show Contact Distance Search in Advance Search > Address Fields. but still something is missing. Can you please guide me here. I am new to CiviCRM and Drupal. Please see the new image I have added in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM Contact Distance Search is a Drupal module, Advance Search is a core CiviCRM search functionality. The two are not linked what so ever.
CiviCRM Contact Distance Search module allows you to set up a Drupal view so that users on your website can search for particular contacts that are in your CiviCRM database by using a postcode and distance. 
I have recently updated the module to allow a map and use your location
More info can be found here - https://civicrm.org/blog/anil/drupal-views-civicrm-contact-distance-search-with-a-map